# does custom resourceloader work the same in spring boot 1.4.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi I have been using a custom resource loader with spring boot like below for quite some time

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOG.info("Starting up....");        
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Service.class);
    SpringApplication app = builder.application();
    // TODO see if ProtocolResolver can be used here 
    app.setResourceLoader(new EnhancedResourceLoader());
    app.run(args);
}
```

and my custom resource is something like

```
@Aws
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "s3://${cloud.aws.vpc-name}/creds/${cloud.aws.stack-name}/testprops.properties", })
public static class Config {
}
```

This used to work fine before I did the upgrade . Now seems the custom s3 url doesn't get captured in my custom resource loader . Have there been any changes or is there a different way now to do this .Please help

Comment: maybe because your class is static?

Comment: Nop that shouldnt be an issue I guess as the same is a configuration class . Also the same used to work in the prior version .

Answer (score 0):

AS of now to fix as per https://twitter.com/ankinson/status/821401622001684481 I have removed the dependency for spring boot devtools and it works .Guess will test the same in the next 1.5.x release if that fixes it .